# getText(), JavascriptExecutor, innerText, textContent only returning null from a read only field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Critical UPDATE**:
*It appears that, when we reach the page by using Selenium, the read only fields never loads. It's a document.jsp page which loads. But when we reach the page manually, we get that data. I am using ChromeDriver. I think that explains why I am unable to retrieve the read only fields while using Selenium. If anyone knows of a work around, please let me know.*

**UPDATE:** *Since writing this question I have tried innerText again with CSS but it returns "`&nbsp;`" instead of "Bronze". So it looks like I am able to retrieve something. But it's `&nbsp;`. How can I get "Bronze"*

I am trying to retrieve the text from the field of a read only element using ChromDriver. Below is the HTML code. I want to retrieve the String "Bronze"

```
<div class="column label-left" style="width:25%">
    <div class="form-item clearfix null" id="attr_wrapper_1_offerType_t">
        <label class="form-label" for="offerType_t" style="width: 130px"><span style="padding-right: 5px">Offer Type:</span></label>
        <div class="form-element field-wrapper" id="field_wrapper_1_offerType_t" style="padding-left:130px">
            <div class="field" message=""><span class="readonly-wrapper" id="readonly_1_offerType_t">New Business</span></div>
            <div id="msg_1_offerType_t" class="error-hover" data-action-message="" message=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item clearfix null" id="attr_wrapper_1_dealClass_t">
        <label class="form-label" for="dealClass_t" style="width: 130px"><span style="padding-right: 5px">Deal Class:</span></label>
        <div class="form-element field-wrapper" id="field_wrapper_1_dealClass_t" style="padding-left:130px">
            <div class="field" message=""><span class="readonly-wrapper" id="readonly_1_dealClass_t">Bronze</span></div>
            <div id="msg_1_dealClass_t" class="error-hover" data-action-message="" message=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item clearfix attr-spacer" style="height: 25px;"></div>
    <div class="form-item clearfix attr-spacer" style="height: 25px;"></div>
</div>
```

I am using id="readonly_1_dealClass_t" but it returns null.
I have also tried xpath="//span[contains(@id,"dealClass")]". It returns null too.

First of all, **getText()** on id, xpath, CSS all of them returns null. Then I tried all the below options.

I have also tried using **JavascriptExecutor** and retrieving the text(), but it doesn't help either.
I have also tried **innerText** and **textContent** for the above id but without success. 
I have waits for 60 seconds until element is visible. It returns true. Which means its visible. But it just refuses to retrieve the string "Bronze".
I also tried getAttribute("value") too. Without success obviously.

I also thought I could use the id="field_wrapper_1_dealClass_t" and use innerText on it. Still no success. That one just returns a lot of whitespace.

What else can I try to retrieve the string "Bronze"?

PS: I don't have issues with Firefox. Chrome just refuses to go ahead. And business need is to stick with only Chrome right now. So I have to get this working in Chrome. Please help.

I hope I have been clear and I hope I have furnished enough HTML code.

**UPDATE:** 
This returns [] for value, ie blank.

```
final String script = "return arguments[0].getAttribute('innerHTML')";

WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='field']/span)[21]"));
String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, randomRow);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This returns [ ] too:

```
String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='readonly-wrapper' and starts-with(@id,'readonly_') and contains(@id,'_dealClass_t')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Without seeing your code that leads up to the problem, there are only guesses that can be applied. If the element is auto-populated via javascript after the page is rendered, it is possible the element actually contains `&nbsp;` when checked. If you sleep awhile (not the recommended long term solution) before checking the content, does it find `bronze`?

Comment: try using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='field']/span[contains(.,'Bronze')]")).getText();` i know this is not ue solution, but first see if you are able to get The Text

Comment: @Ron Norris - It actually is sleeping for about 10 seconds. But still returns that &nbsp. I enter this page by filling data in the previous page. When I reach this page, these fields are populated with the data retrieved from the previous page. It is indeed js rendering this page. It just refuses to find "Bronze". But on the page I can see Bronze. Can you tell me what other info would help you help me?

Comment: @kushal - It returns "Unable to locate element"

Comment: @SteroidKing666 : ok now try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='field']/span")).getText();

Comment: @kushal - It actually should be (//div[@class='field']/span)[21] but it returns null. The one you posted returned the text perfectly fine from some other field. So, I played around and figured that Chrome Developer Tool highlights my "Bronze" field with (//div[@class='field']/span)[21]. But somehow it returns null through Selenium. :(

Comment: @SteroidKing666 : check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after several trial and error runs it turns out that the page does not load completely when logging into it using Selenium. I copied the URL which opens using Selenium  and compared it with the one which opens manually. They were different. The part after `formCreate` right after `document.jsp` was completely different for the Selenium loaded page. So, to avoid too much complications, I used `driver.get("url")` with the `"url"` being the actual URL and then let it open. This loaded the fields correctly and I was able to do the validations.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to retrieve the String **Bronze** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the visibility of the element as follows :

```
String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='readonly-wrapper' and starts-with(@id,'readonly_') and contains(@id,'_dealClass_t')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: That's already done. That and also have got thread sleep too. That's why I am perplexed how it's not retrieving.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `thread sleep` use the solution provided within the answer and let me know the status. If you see an error update the question with your _code trials_ and the _error stack trace_ for further analysis.

Comment: It returns [ ] and I have updated it in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to get that using below by fetching 'innerHTML' attribute:

```
final String script = "return arguments[0].getAttribute('innerHTML')";

WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='field']/span)[21]"));
String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, randomRow);
```

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Bronze] but found [null]

Comment: Please see my update above. It appears that Selenium does not load the read only fields. Its a javascript document page. I have never before faced this issue where Selenium does not load the data but reaching the page manually loads it.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 is it possible for you to share the URL?

Comment: sorry it cannot be shared due to business privacy reasons. I have figured out it does not go to that page while using Selenium. I have communicated it to the web developer. I am trying to figure out why it wouldn't work using Selenium.

Comment: what is the 'value' captured using above code? is it Null?

Comment: Yes it is null.